# RTF template coding using xdofx function

Tags: rtf

I use following logic in print check

Template layout
Name
Addressline1
Addressline2
City,zip
My goal is to SHIFT addressline1 into the Name line when condition is met.
For some reason I have space in the Name and second line is printed as Addressline1
So check becomes invalid. Any help would be appreciated!

I tried different logics. When I remove Name from the template the Addressline1 printed correctly as a Name.
But I need to keep the name if condition is not met I need the current Name to be printed